# Why GCM supports server key?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Why GCM server supports Server Key only for Push Notification except remaining keys like as Android,Browser and IOS key. What is the reason?

Comment: because the message sent to you or from your device is received by the server and then broadcasted further to the mentioned regid or list of regid's(user device id).

Comment: Hey kumar. Have you seen my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829) in your previous post?

Answer (score 1):

GCM supports Server or browser key both and android key and IOS key is for android and IOS development. and its uniq for your google api key platform

Comment: I initially used android api key. For the past two years, it was working fine. But suddenly, for past two days i am not getting push notification.After changing the Android key to server key its working now. Can u  know the reason why android api key suddenly stops working?

Answer (score 0):

When we are creating key to GCM in google developer console we will be using server key, because push messages are sent by the server. When creating the server key we can create with specific ip address also. It is used to authenticate our  server with google server. IF user is created the key with particular ip address then the google server will accept the request from that server only. If user is not giving any ip address at the time of key creation then google server will accept request from any ip address.