# GCM - How to Generate a Server API Key For Android Push Notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use push notification service on my Android project, but when I try to generate a server key, I notice that Google's developers console changed and I can't find where I can generate my server key. I looked at a lot of tutorials but still I can't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: There is now a visible note in the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) saying:

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the Firebase Console using the [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging) tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/) without affecting their existing configuration.

---

Just retrieved a part of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829).

1. Go to your [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. On the left-pane, click on  <kbd>Credentials</kbd>
3. Under the Credentials Tab, Click on  <kbd>Create Credentials</kbd>
4. Select  <kbd>API Key</kbd>
5. Select  <kbd>Server Key</kbd>
6. Fill out the details.
7. Click on  <kbd>Create</kbd>

The Server Key should be available by then.

<s>PS: Just tried it out, this still is a way to generate a Server Key.</s>

Answer (score 1):

please consider changing from google cloud messaging to firebase cloud messaging
google now recommend developers to use FCM instead of GCM

link here: https://firebase.google.com/features/