# Azure Notification Hub error 401

Tags: c#, azure, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

Im having a bit of issue setting up a console application that will send push notifications to iOS/Android devices.

**Error shown is below:**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
occurred. ---System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The remote server
returned an error: (401)
Unauthorized..TrackingId:ea158550-8761-41f8-821d-dbcb88fcce56,TimeStamp:18/07/2016
08:58:21 ---System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
error: (401) Unauthorized.    at
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   
at
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationRequestAsyncResult`1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__3(TAsyncResult
thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)    at
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:


Exception rethrown at [0]:    at
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
result)    at
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubManager.EndSendNotification(IAsyncResult
result)    at
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
requiresSynchronization)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
XamarinAzurePushNotification.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in
B:\Personal Development\Visual Studio
2015\AzurePushNotifications\XamarinAzurePushNotification.Server\Program.cs:line
26
```

Here is my code for the console application:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://ConnectionStringName.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=ConnectionStringKey", "HubName");

    var iOS_alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello. This is a iOS notification! Tada!\", \"sound\":\"default\"}}";
    hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(iOS_alert).Wait();

    var android_alert = "{\"message\": \"Can I interest you in a once in a lifetime push notification?!\", \"title\":\"Ding, dong!\"}";
    hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(android_alert).Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE SENT");
}
```

If anyone could give me a hand with this it'd be great.

Comment: Can you verify if your API Key is a Server Key? See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829).

Comment: You see I have tested my application in Azure by using there test push notification function and my app is receiving notifications but when i tried to implement the same in my console application(server) it just gives that error.

Comment: I just checked there now and it seems that I am already using the server key.

Comment: That's odd.. Have you also checked the Recommended Actions in the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) for Error Code 401?

Comment: I have but it doesn't seem to help me much...

Comment: Did you try sending a simple curl request? Can you post the response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature`; instead use the  `DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature`.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the answers above did not work, please check if the server/PC has the correct Date Time configured. In my case, on a client, the server had wrong Date Time settings, and I got the Error:

Error Code: 0x17
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:4c2cdbg3-e1a8-4240-b963-d6f55e8f2c76_G29,TimeStamp:8/23/2018 8:58:27 AM ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationRequestAsyncResult`1.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__26_3(TAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Very frustrating until I found the problem.

Comment: Here or in the same problem, for example, server data is a later time.