# Error while invoking mobilefirst push notification adapter Failed to invoke Google GCM push service

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

i given a proper key and sender ID. I tried with both server key and browser key. still getting same error.

console shows this error:

```
[ERROR   ] FPWSE1055E: Failed to invoke Google GCM push service.
GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Authentication has failed for sender key starting with 'AIzaSyDK')
```

and the Browser shows:

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "result": "Notification sent to user :: someuser"
}
```

Comment: You should use a Server key. What is your mfp version?

Comment: Does this SenderId and key work otherwise? Have you been able to use it successfully in another application?

Comment: i am using 7.1.Problem is with updated browser. Don't know how to create server key from my browser.--Idan Adar

Comment: Problem is with Key.it is not working in another project also. But i followed below answer and it is working fine.---- Vivin K

Answer (score 0):

You might be affected with the recent *changes*. Try what I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829). Specifically, try generating a Server Key again, but this time, through the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), then try a request again. If you're requests are still failing, and if you can see an error from the GCM Server, I suggest contacting [GCM Support](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/support).

**If you are just starting to use GCM**, instead of creating a project in the Google Developers Console, do it in the Firebase Console. After creating the project, simply use the auto-generated Server Key. Here are the steps where to find the Server Key:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>CREATE NEW PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Fill in your desired Project Name and select your Country. After this, the new Project should be active.
3. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
4. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

---

**For old GCM projects**, you can simply Import the project to the Firebase Console:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>IMPORT PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Select the project you want to import and your country.
3. Click on <kbd>ADD FIREBASE</kbd>. After this, the new Project should be active.
4. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
5. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

Comment: @Raghu You're welcome. Feel free to accept this answer as correct or if you did a separate solution, you can answer your own question. :)