# Push notification - Server API Key

Tags: azure, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have been using GCM to send Push notifications for a long time, in the past days, the sending log starts give me the error:

```
The Push Notification System rejected the request because of an invalid credential
```

After searching on the web, it seems that a Server API Key is now required to get service working again.

The API Key was created and restricted to IP of my production server on Amazon.

When I try to register the Server API Key in Azure GCM, I got an `error 401 unauthorized`.

Can anyone give me any suggestion? I don't know what to do anymore, my users can't access our system because authentication token is not being sent. Thanks.

Screen errors:
[image: Server API Key]
[image: Azure GCM Error]

Comment: Please **ALWAYS** keep your API Keys a **Secret**.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a visible note in the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) saying:

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the Firebase Console using the [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging) tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/) without affecting their existing configuration.

**Migrating from GCM to FCM** fixes the issue for 401 Unauthorized Error.

**If you are just starting to use GCM**, instead of creating a project in the Google Developers Console, do it in the Firebase Console. After creating the project, simply use the auto-generated Server Key. Here are the steps where to find the Server Key:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>CREATE NEW PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Fill in your desired Project Name and select your Country. After this, the new Project should be active.
3. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
4. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

**For old GCM projects**, you can simply Import the project to the Firebase Console:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>IMPORT PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Select the project you want to import and your country.
3. Click on <kbd>ADD FIREBASE</kbd>. After this, the new Project should be active.
4. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
5. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829) for more details.

Comment: Hi !

Very thanks for you help !

The new FCM Server API Key was succesfully registered in Azure GCM

When I try send a test notification it now give me a diferent error message :

"The Token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong"

Just started looking for something about this...

Is it a nkow problem ?


Thanks,
Marco Borsoni.

Comment: @ResolveInformtica Hi Marco. So sorry for not getting back to you in this post. Were you able to resolve your issue? If not, could you provide more details?