# How to solve this issue i want to send notifications

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging, gcmtaskservice

Here i want to send notifications for mobile. i am trying like this i getting error like this.

---

{"multicast_id":9154934162102180737,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

---

i can not understand what is **API_ACCESS_KEY**

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxx' );
//$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
$registrationIds = array( "APA91bEbAxYQZuglicZ2Ea5c26MtK07BYyunv14Us5INdjNvy3gy0Anq6V09dv2j21g7n_JERDumynuOp4l9GYA4RUGRjRZb6KJ4JYg9qPN9dlytPsgPKctIMhxfHFQSr9FfDjobZUJU" );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Comment: issue is that you pass registation id (GCM) is not registered. you have to pass GCM Id generated by this please check in. pass valid GCM ID issue will be slove.

Comment: GCM ID means What, how to register.

Comment: $registrationIds is my mobile number unique token id

Comment: @ JD The Real Hero tell me solution actually i spended 2 days still i can't get solution

Comment: Are you sure you're using the corresponding Sender ID for registration token you're sending a message to? And also, **never** disclose your API Keys to the public.

Comment: Now i am getting like this error Unauthorized

Error 401

Comment: @Al how to solve this one

Comment: Which one? The 401? Can you check if you're using a proper Server Key? See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829)

Comment: @SujiniR How was your 401? Was it fixed?

Comment: I am not fixed still getting same error i don't know what will do

Comment: @SujiniR What error are you still receiving?

Answer (score 0):

@SujiniR First you register your app in Google Cloud Messaging and get API Access KEY and Send ID, Link:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

Then, Save Your api access key in :

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'api_key_recieved_from_google_by_above_process' );
```

Then use SenderID in Android Application to get RegistrationId, copy or send that registrationId to server and use it in:

```
$registrationIds = array(registrationID);
```

Answer (score 0):

So basing from our discussion in the comments, it seems you were using the wrong Sender ID. You should always use the corresponding Sender ID to which the registration token was, well, *registered*. Your client app can receive from multiple Sender IDs, so long as it is *tied* to it. Else it will return a [MismatchSender](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes):

> A registration token is tied to a certain group of senders. When a client app registers for GCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. **If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work.**

Comment: Mr @Al tell me which one i did wrong key SERVER KEY  or mobile REGISTER KEY

Comment: @SujiniR Hard to tell with the details you provided. What client app are you using?