# Azure Notification Hub GCM Authentication Error 401

Tags: azure, authentication, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

When I am entering the GCM API Key to the Notification Hub, it gives me the error:

```
{"error":{"message":"SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with GCM.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized...TrackingId:4de00134-abe4-41de-9785-009dda22c2bc_M0_M0_G7,
TimeStamp:10/28/2016 8:06:46 AM","code":"BadRequest"}}
```

Can anyone help me to get out of this?

Comment: Are you using the appropriate Server Key from the Firebase Console?

Comment: i am not using firebase i am using Google cloud messaging(GCM).

Comment: I'm not saying you are. But new Server Keys are to be generated in the Firebase Console. See the note I linked in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829).

Comment: ohh.. thanks @AL. it works thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

For new users of GCM. You should use a Server Key that is auto-generated after creating/importing a project in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/):

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the Firebase Console using the Cloud Messaging tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the Firebase console without affecting their existing configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should import the existing project(s) into FireBase and Google automatically generate the Server-Key and use that in Azure Notification Hub.

Server key is now enhanced, but Google recommends to use the latest key.

FireBase URL: https://console.firebase.google.com

Click the "Gear" icon >> Project Settings >> Select "Cloud Messaging"

[image]