# GCM API Key from existing GCM project?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I am working on an existing project from another developer and I need to get the GCM Server Key for PubNub settings since it was accidentally removed.

Is there any way I can retrieve it from Google settings? I can't find it in credentials and project settings.

I don't want to upgrade to Firebase for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to actually ***upgrade*** to Firebase. You just have to ***migrate the project*** so that you can use the auto-generated Server Key in it. AFAIK, configurations should still the same after the migration of the project so there's no need to update any code.

This **is** the way it should be done in order to generate a new Server Key, as stated in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key):

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the Firebase Console using the [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging) tab of the **Settings** panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/) without affecting their existing configuration.

If you ever decide to go with the project migration, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829) for the steps.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, I will try it later. Thanks

Comment: @JunM Were you able to try it out?

Comment: @AL. I migrated to Firebase and a little while ago my existing GCM apps still worked. I only ever set up a browser key so that I could access the webpage on my server from any location. I now find that the old GCM apps now always give me a Not authorized 401 response. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @NickT When using FCM, you must always use the *Server Key* found in the *Cloud Messaging* Tab in your Firebase Console.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add), register here by adding platform, you will get your API Key & Sender ID

Comment: Is there a way I can these info on existing gcm project? Aside from registering new one.

Comment: You have to register your own project