# android: Already one year previous working GCM Key is not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was using a GCM server key from last one year(June 2015). But suddenly this key stopped working from September 2016. Now I have no reason to explain why its not working. I have not changed any thing.

I also verify that key using in my server code is same in Google Developer console and its same.

Please help me to understand why this key is not working. Or I have done something wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API key for GCM is suddenly invalid? Unauthorized (401) error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789264/api-key-for-gcm-is-suddenly-invalid-unauthorized-401-error)

Comment: Have you checked what error are you receiving when the push fails?

Comment: Its 401 Error. Actually I have to give reason to my seniors. I also tried another GCM key and its working fine. I also used FCM key and its also working fine. But till now I don't have reason. Why a one year old working GCM key stopped working? I need a reason so that I can have way to define. Seniors want to know what was the problem so that in future this will not happen again.

Comment: Were you using an Android API Key before it started acting up? Or was it a Server Key right from the start?

Comment: it was a server key from starting. I created two server key for my own company server and another for third party server. now third party server key is not working. I check this key on my server also and its not working.