# The request's Authentication (Server-) Key contained an invalid or malformed FCM-Token (a.k.a. IID-Token). Error 401

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

try to POST FCM from Postman, but got error message
"The request's Authentication (Server-) Key contained an invalid or malformed FCM-Token (a.k.a. IID-Token).

Error 401"

note: copy auth key from Project credentials-Server key

url : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
header
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization : key=AAAAQJ50ukk:Gf9m5PCwpwb1EG .....aovqy
Body : 
{
  "to": "",
  "data": 
  {
    "title":"Test"
    "message":"Test Message"
   }
}

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: hello, i am facing the same issue, any chance you found any resolution for this. I am stuck on this from quite some time.

Comment: Hi, I have also facing same problem. Because i have used my previous fire base project. It means i have used existing fire base project google service.json in new ionic project. So when generate token it will not same. Thats the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789264/api-key-for-gcm-is-suddenly-invalid-unauthorized-401-error/37801206#37801206

Look at this. It will help to you.