# How to update new API key on current firebase project

Tags: firebase, passwords

For some reason, my firebase project apikey associate with database changed. I can still create another api key, update into the application.

But when user try to reset password, the link use the old key and lead to "Your request to reset your password has expired or the link has already been used" (I think I read this problem somewhere and now I found the reason).

Is there anyway to update new api key for an existing firebase project?

Thank you

Comment: By the API Key, do you mean something like the Server Key for FCM?

Comment: @AL.: I mean Browser Key for FCM that we can find at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<projectid>. I think reset password use Browser Key to communicate with database and access through link https://<projectid>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action

Comment: I haven't encountered this before. Maybe you can try the same steps when re-generating a Server key as I tried [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37741826/4625829).

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was't what I looking for. I am able to create keys but the "Reset Password" function on firebase need a "Browser Key" to completed the task, my situation was that browser key has changed on developer console but it still use the old key cause "Reset Password" not able to perform

Comment: I see. I'm not really sure how you set which Browser Key to use in the Firebase Project. Haven't seen anything similar too.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway AL. :)

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Nico I updated the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow, my original apiKey was recovered. You can find the original key (which were deleted from console.google.com) associated with the application on the main firebase page, through

> Overview > Project settings > GENERAL

Basically, when users requested to recover the password, firebase will send an email with recovery link. If you have a look at the link, you will see the API included in the link is the one that no longer exists.

I recommend you to contact firebase support. I don't have an official way to solve the issue but here is quick I can think of, following as

> 1. Create new API at console.google.com > choose your firebase project
> 2. Create a page with a function that can read URL parameters. Make it receive firebase recovery password URL and replace dead API with new
>      one, then redirect you to new firebase recovery password URL
> 3. Edit email template by adding the page you created on step 2, with firebase recovery full URL as a parameter

To be more accurate, here is an example.
I have my project called "MyFirebaseProj", my domain is "example.com"

1. I go to console.google.com, choose "MyFirebaseProj", on API Manager panel, choose Credentials > Credentials. Click on Create credentials > API Key. So I got a new API key call "MyNewLongAPI".
2. I created a recover-password.html password and have this javascript function https://codepen.io/hieunc229/pen/mWwVbv (this one will read the firebase url, get oobCode and generate new URL). Edit the javascript so it will redirect the user to new URL. Upload this one into my host (mydomain.org/recover-password.html)
3. On Firebase console, Authentication > Email Template > Reset Password. Change the link to something like

`<a href='http://example.com/recover-password.html?url=%LINK%'>%LINK%</a>`

Then save it

Now when user go into your recover password page, they will be redirected into firebase url with new API and it should works

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone run into the same issue, as I get in touch with Firebase team and they are investigating about it. Currently there haven't been a way to help it.

Comment: have you got any solution. I have the same problem my API key and API key on the link of reset password or email verification are not the same.

Comment: I don't remember how my API Key was recovered. Though, have you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42758633/5775993

Comment: I haven't facing this issue for a while and don't know what's up now. If you haven't already, try to contact firebase team and see how it goes!