# Firebase 3 Password Recovery Link Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, change-password, password-recovery

I've been working on my app with Firebase for several months now. I hooked up the password reset code about 5 months ago and when I would test it, I'd get the password rest email sent, click the link and everything would work fine. I haven't signed in with that particular account in 5 months so I forgot the password. Now when I get the pw reset email everytime I click the link I repeatedly get:

> Try resetting your password again. Your request to reset your password
>   has expired or the link has already been used

I'm using Firebase 3 via cocoapods as of Aug 2016 and never upgraded or installed anything from any of the older versions. I'm also using swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1.

I would upload code but everything is working fine because the email is getting sent, the problem seems to be on FB's end.

**What's the issue?**

Comment: Have you found a solution? Might be a bug on Firebase's side.

Comment: @Nico nah nothing. I'm not sure what the issue is. I've been so busy focusing on other app issues I actually forgot about it

Comment: Check this, maybe it can help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42758633/1294968

Comment: @nico thanks for the help! I'm going to try it tomorrow. I'm working on a really big app by myself and it's A LOT of work!! I have so many diff issues I have to attend to that I sometimes forget the initial issues. It's a process... I really appreciate the help though . I found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160622/firebase-reset-password-link-not-working I'm going to try the link you sent and this also. I'll let you know the outcome

Comment: @Nico I'm sending an email to FB tech support. I'll let you know their response

Comment: @Nico I contacted them and they got back to me within a few hours. You can select an urgency level of low, medium, high, and critical. I selected medium and they got back to me FAST. Anyway I posted what they wrote below and tried some of their suggestions but still all nil. As soon as I get a response or resolution I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

This is an update for anyone who runs into this problem. This is the response Firebase tech support sent back. It isn't the answer but rather an idea of what they'll ask you if you have the same problem. You get up to 5 free questions per 365 days so why waste one.

> Hi there,
>
> Could you please try resetting your password on your console and let
>   us see if it works there. Also, did you generate a new API key for
>   your project? If yes, then it's possible that your old API key is
>   still being used by your app. Could you please check whether the API
>   key is same? The API key from your Firebase project and your app
>   should be the same.
>
> Please update your app's Firebase config and check if the API keys
>   match your console's. For Android, download the updated
>   google-services.json file. See more details [here](http://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app). For iOS, download
>   the updated GoogleService-Info.plist file. See more details [here](http://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app). For
>   Web, follow the config as seen in the [docs](http://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app). If the steps above still
>   doesn't work, please provide the details below to further investigate
>   the issue. Old API key and new API key used. Platform and Firebase SDK
>   version used? Date and time you started encountering this issue. Error
>   logs and full stack trace. Screenshots of your API keys. Let me know
>   if you have any other Firebase related issues/questions. Thank you for
>   using Firebase. :)

I actually had another API key inside my console that was never used. I deleted it like they suggested and the Firebase Recovery email was still broken. I changed my Google.Console password and it still didn't work. I sent them all the required information. As soon as I get a response and hopefully a resolution I'll post it.

Comment: I tried resetting the password from the console but it does not work. I am getting "Try resetting your password again. Your request to reset your password has expired or the link has already been used". Any solution?

Comment: @iMDroid The problem was caused by another part of google console. I forgot the name of it but I’ll upload some screen shots of it in a few hours. Hopefully it’ll help you out. I’ll send you a message when I do

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't understand why and then I realised something... as it was new environment, I exported users from another environment and on this one, I just forgot to **activate authentication by email**...

My mistake but I thing Firebase should make it clearer in their error warnings.

Comment: it was working before, I never changed anything. I'll look in the console again and let you know. I hope your correct. Thanks

Comment: Which section are you referring to?I just looked inside the Firebase console and under Authentication I see: Users, Sign-In Method, Email Templates. Under Email Templates I see: Email Address Verification, Password Reset, Email Address Change. None of them have an option for "authenticating by email". If your referring to: Authentication > Sign-In Method > Email/Password I already had that selected as Enable. I'm using that to sign in and out of my app and it works fine.

Comment: @LanceSamaria Yes I meant `Authentication > Sign-In Method > Email/Password`. Nevermind then.

Comment: Thanks anyway :) Whenever I get it fixed I'll send you a message with the resolution

Comment: If you find the solution whatever it is, just post it here, it might help other people with the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: of course I will, from all that help I've gotten through here and meetups I'll help anyone. Gotta pay it forward :)