# How to create new key for FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In GCM was feature to create new API key, so on my current project different keys were used for staging and prod environment. But now according to info from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) new keys created for GCM are not valid.

How can I create few FCM keys for one project?

Answer (score 3):

For GCM or FCM, you'll be needing a **Server Key**. Steps are below on how to Create a New or Import a project to have a valid Server Key.

**If you are just starting to use GCM**, instead of creating a project in the Google Developers Console, do it in the Firebase Console. After creating the project, simply use the auto-generated Server Key. Here are the steps where to find the Server Key:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>CREATE NEW PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Fill in your desired Project Name and select your Country. After this, the new Project should be active.
3. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
4. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

**For old GCM projects**, you can simply Import the project to the Firebase Console:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>IMPORT PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Select the project you want to import and your country.
3. Click on <kbd>ADD FIREBASE</kbd>. After this, the new Project should be active.
4. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
5. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

---

<sub>Portion taken from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829).</sub>

Comment: Project already imported. Thing here that this project contains FCM key, that used by our app server to send notifications. I need to create not new project but only key.

Comment: @PavloI. Why do you need a new Server Key? The idea here is that using a single Server Key should be enough, unless you're going to create a different project (*which you don't want to*).  Or are you looking to [regenerate the Server Key](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37741826/4625829)?

Comment: It is an requirement to decouple different environments. But if it is not supported by FCM seems we'll use single token for all.

Comment: I think you are referring to having separate Sender IDs for staging and prod environment, not an API key, like what was mentioned in the [XMPP docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#connecting): *...should use a different GCM sender ID to avoid any risks of sending test messages to production users or sending upstream messages from production traffic over test connections.* For that case, creating a separate project is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To add upon needing separate keys for both development and prod, once you create a new firebase project for your other environment, you'll have a new google-services.json file to incorporate with the new keys.  At this point you can have your production google-services.json file in the app/src/release directory to keep them separate.
  More info here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin